# Javascript tag wont close inside php loop

Tags: php, javascript, loops, syntax

This is a snippet of the code that doesn't work right. The closing `</script>` tag of the javascript for some reason isn't recognized. The javascript is for a check all box that will check or uncheck all the checkboxes generated with each form. Each form is separate so I tried to slim down my code by including in the php loop. I had a version of this code working but it involved repeating the same javascript sample multiple times. If you can think of a way to do this differently, feel free to improve the code. At the moment though all I need to figure out why the closing tag of the javascript doesn't work.

```
foreach($words as $word){
    $i++;
    $qry = "Select * FROM subs WHERE type = '$word'"; 
    $q = mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error()); 
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    checked=false;

    function checkedAll<?=$i?>(frm<?=$i?>) 
    { 
        var aa= document.getElementById('frm<?=$i?>'); 
        if(checked == false) {
            checked = true
        } 
        else{
            checked = false
        } 

        for(var i =0; i < aa.elements.length; i++) {
            aa.elements[i].checked = checked;
        }
    } 
    </script>
<?
    echo '<form action="attacher.php" method="POST" id="frm'.$i.'" >';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="template" value="16">';
    echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
    echo "<tr><td colspan=4 align='center'><strong>$word</strong></td> <td><input type='submit' value='Add to Template'></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><th><input type='checkbox' name='checkall".$i."' onclick='checkedAll".$i."'(frm".$i.");'></th><th colspan=3> CONTROLS</th> <th>$word's</th> </tr>";

    // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {   
        // echo out the contents of each row into  table
        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="word[]" value="'.$row['id'].'"</td>';
        echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
        echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
        echo '<td><a href="attacher.php?template=16&word=' . $row['id'] . '">Attach</a></td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['word'] . '</td>';
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    // close table>
    echo "</table><br>";
    echo '</form>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Sure php short tags are allowed in your configuration?

Comment: What's a *JavaScript tag*? EDIT: Oh, you're talking about the HTML `script` tag?

Comment: Umm, why do you use `<script "text/javascript">` instead `<script type="text/javascript">`?

Comment: remove the space in </script > (</script>). BTW why are you echoing a piece of javascript inside a php for loop? You can do something better than this, create a global function which switches every checkbox in a form.

Comment: In fact, you could get ride of the `"text/javascript"` altogether. Also, I see that there is a tailing space in the `</script >`. Just to be safe (though this shouldn't raise an issue), I'd change it to `</script>`.

Comment: I don't recommend using PHP's short open tag (`<?`) in your code, as it can break horribly if `short_open_tag = Off` in *php.ini*. See http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/01/12/php-short-open-tag/

Comment: Short tags are correctly enabled and working.

Comment: @DigitalFire I'm suggesting that short tags are a bad idea in the first place. e.g. If you moved your code to another server, things could go boom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to mention that the convention of code you use (even if it is one - but I doubt it) isn't very neat.

Why don't you use just some safe variants?
How about something like this:

```
<?php
  //here what you want to do first    
?>

<?php
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">
          ....
        </script>';
?>

<?php
   echo 'rest of your code';
?>
```

I really don't recommend using shorttags anyway...